# Event (table content editable) and send to PHP file to update my database

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I try to enable edit the table content and try to send the changes to PHP file to update my database. My JavaScript works only for display the alphabets to other propose but when try to add another event it does not work .. as http request ..etc

NOW I am asking about why the JavaScript `onblur` and on `click` events are  not working. Please help me.

filter.php

```
<?php @ob_start();
session_start(); 
include('database.php');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/alphabet.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<div class="content-side">
<?php
include("filter2.php");
?>
<button id="button-1" title="save" type="button" disabled>Save</button>
</div>


<div class="filter-sid">
<form action="filter.php" method="GET" name="filter" id="filter">
<label>Type :</label><br>
                        <inputtype="radio"/><label for="res1">...</label>
                        <input type="radio" checked/><label>...</label><br>
                        <lable>Letters :</lable>
                        <br><br>
                    </form>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript file alphabet.js:

```
$(window).load(function () {

        $('td[contenteditable=true]').blur(function () {
      $(this).parent('tr').find('button').removeAttr('disabled');

    });
//When a button is clicked find the nearest contenteditable td //element(s) and push their 
    $('button').click(function () {
        var contents = $(this).parents().find('td[contenteditable=true]');
        var contentArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            contentArray[i] = contents[i].innerHTML;
        }
        alert("work :) ");
        //$.post("test.php", contentArray);
    });

    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
    var container = document.getElementById("filter");
    for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        //alert("letter= "+alphabet[i]);

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "alphabet" + i;
        checkbox.value = "" + alphabet[i];
        checkbox.id = "alphabet" + i;
        checkbox.className = "alphabet" + i;

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.htmlFor = "id" + alphabet[i];
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('' + alphabet[i]));
        var br = document.createElement("br");

        container.appendChild(checkbox);
        container.appendChild(label);
        container.appendChild(br);

    }
    ;
    var br2 = document.createElement("br");
    container.appendChild(br2);

    var filterBtn = document.createElement('input');
    filterBtn.type = "submit";
    filterBtn.value = "Apply Filter";
    filterBtn.setAttribute("id", "filterbtn");
    filterBtn.setAttribute("classname", "filterbtn");
    filterBtn.setAttribute("class", "filterbtn");
    //filterBtn.setAttribute("onclick","view()");

    container.appendChild(filterBtn);
    container.appendChild(br2);
    container.appendChild(br2);
 });
```

The table display in filter2.php:

```
<?php

//Sanitize the POST values
$type= $_GET['res'];
$data=array();
$alpha=array();
$j=0;
$k=0;
$letter="";
$keywords="";
//for ($r=$checked ;$r>0 ;$r--)
//$alpha[$j++] =$_GET['myArray'+$r];
for($y=0;$y<26;$y++){

    if(isset($_GET['alphabet'.$y])){
        $alpha[$j]= $_GET['alphabet'.$y];  
        $keywords .="alphabet".$y."=".$alpha[$j++]."&";

    }
}
$con=$j;
while ($con>0){
    $letter .="Publisher_Name like '".$alpha[--$con]."%' AND ";
} //letter as string
$keywords .="res=".$_GET['res'];//to add to link for pagination

$per_page = 14;
if ($j>0)
    $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('Publisher_Name') FROM Publishers where "  . $letter . " is_reported=1"); //get the number of contents); //get the number of contents
else 
    $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('Publisher_Name') FROM Publishers where is_reported=1"); //get the number of contents

$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page); // get the number of pages

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page; //get the starting content id of each page
if ($j>0)
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Publishers where "  . $letter . " is_reported=1 LIMIT $start, $per_page");
else 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Publishers where is_reported=1 LIMIT $start, $per_page");

//echo content of each page
if (($query)) {
    $info1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
(($info1 == null)) {
        ?>
        <div id="result" >
            <?php
                echo '<p id="error"> No results found .</p> ';
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    else if ($info1 != null) {
        ?>
        <div id="result">
        <?php
        echo' <table cellpadding="2"  width="100%">';
        echo '<tr >';
        echo '<td id="tds">Name p</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        do{
        echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td contenteditable='true'>" . $info1['nemep'] . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        }while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) ;
        echo' </table>';
        ?>
        </div>
            <?php
        }
    }//if query


    $prev = $page - 1;
    $next = $page + 1;

    if (!($page <= 1)) {
        echo "<a  href='filter.php?page=$prev&$keywords'>Prev</a> ";
    }

    if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages) {

        for ($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++) {
            echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="filter.php?page=' . $x . '&'.$keywords.'">' . $x . '</a></strong> ' : '<a href="filter.php?page=' . $x . '&'.$keywords.'">' . $x . '</a> ';
        }
    }

    if (!($page >= $pages)) {
        echo "<a  href='filter.php?page=$next&$keywords'>Next</a>";
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console?

Comment: Did you mean the console in Chrom developer tool ? how to show the error in the concol because nothing display ?

Comment: nothing it's white box in console tab in chrome dev too .

Comment: try replacing $('td[contenteditable=true]').blur(function ()......... with $(' body td[contenteditable=true]').blur(function ()

Comment: the same no reaction .. blur and onclick method not work  !! :( really thank you for ur time

Comment: please try to create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work ..

```
$(document).on('blur', '.editor', function () {
    console.log("good!");
    var dataTask = $(this).attr("id");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-task");
    var name = document.getElementById(dataTask).innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "admin_update.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&id=" + id,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#msg").html(data);

        },
        timeout: 3000
    });
});
```